# How to show the google recaptcha image verification every time after click of checkbox?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am using Google recaptcha v2. Here, I want the image verification to show every time once the captcha checkbox is clicked to verify.

[image]

I have tried passing the **type: 'image'** property value but it does not work.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div id="captcha_container"></div>
      <div id="captcha-error" class="error-msg"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=checkGrecaptchaToLoad&render=explicit"></script>
```

**JS**

```
function checkGrecaptchaToLoad() {
  grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
     'sitekey' : siteKeyValue,
     'callback' : verifyCaptchaCallback,
     'type': 'image'
  });
}
```

Here the **siteKeyValue** is the google site key.
I have passed the property type and value as image but no luck.

Please let me know if there is any way to show the image verification every time.

Comment: I don't see the documentation provide any option for that. And I don't know what exactly the point is supposed to be in the first place. Google has deliberately created this in a way that disrupts the user's work flow as little as possible, and that includes _not_ requiring them to solve yet another riddle, if Google has already determined they are not a bot.